# Children of flex box don't align to bottom (flex end)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm just introducing myself to [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex?v=control) and from what I understand if I have a `flex` parent, then I can align the children of the parent that are on a single row with the `align-items` rule. However, my children are not changning their alignment as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/b9L09gsa/

The content remains at the top instead of at the bottom like I would like. The idea is to have the logo div and nav items align neatly at the bottom. Clearly I don't understand something, any help would be great!

Comment: A useful reference I look back to constantly is [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need those properties on the flex container, not the flex items:

```
#nav-contain {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
#logo, .nav-item-contain {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9L09gsa/1/

To override individual flex items, use `align-self` instead:

```
#nav-contain {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#logo, .nav-item-contain {
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9L09gsa/2/